Why is air pressure different between the inside and the outside of my house?
I have two identical barometers. I made sure they were calibrated to each other in the same room. Then, weeks ago, I placed one outside.
Right now, the outside one reads $30^\circ\text{F}$ and $1030\,\text{hPa}$ whereas the inside one reads $66^\circ\text{F}$ and $1020\,\text{hPa}$. These values have been in this same ballpark for hours.
Knowing that ideal gas laws involve closed systems and this one is a decidedly open one, I can't figure out how to think about what's happening here. My house is a fairly tightly built modern house, but even so there are many cracks and crevices where air pressure from the outside can seep inside or vice versa.
What is maintaining this pressure difference? I thought that maybe it was because the house is warmer, but it is closer to a closed system, and shouldn't air warm up and expand as it enters the house, thus increasing the house pressure?
My prediction is that they should have been equalized, but a pressure difference has been persistent.
Perhaps posed another way — is this consistent with the behavior of gases in general in an open system with this temperature difference, or is my house unusual (in this case, likely an appliance of some kind is driving this)?

Swap the two and see what happens. The different temperatures may well lead to different readings, even if ‘calibrated’ to each other initially.

Good idea. So, I swapped them and waited 10 minutes. Before switching, the outside one said 1030 hPa and the inside one said 1015 hPa. Then I swapped them. The now-outside-formerly-inside one says 1028 hPa, and the now-inside-formerly-outside one says 1015 hPa. This is 7 hours later according to StackExchange, and it's been like these readings the whole time. I didn't check the temperature but it's still cold outside and warm inside.

A difference of 15 hPa is unlikely large. Check it with the barometer in your smartphone. You may need to download the barometer app. That barometer measures the pressure immediately, it does not need 10 minutes.

See: Temperature with or without shelter, real or felt, dry or humid, what is the difference?   https://tempest-earth.translate.goog/resources/dry-heat-vs-humid-heat/?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=fr&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=sc

What kind of barometer they are? For example, water barometers and aneroids (predictably) suffer from temperature dependence due to the non-ideal vacuum in the sealed part.

Another possible confounding factor: Appliances that move air. Some (gas/petroleum) burners suck in inside air and expel it through the chimney, and some monoblock AC-units do the same. Both will cause inside pressure to be a bit lower than outside pressure.

@user13964273 - They are this product: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0B6J2SQY1/

A small $\Delta p$ on the order of pascals could be explained by heating or AC, but this is obviously a measurement error. An actual pressure difference of 1 kPa = 1 kN/m² between the inside and outside of a house would easily destroy windows, doors or even masonry.

" So, I swapped them and waited 10 minutes" That's where you went wrong. Barometers react pretty much instantaneous. By waiting 10 minutes, you allowed the temperature of the barometer to change.

I suspect the heating system is the primary reason.  Could you elaborate on what mechanism does the heating?  And is there active ventilation?

Cool observations. Never did this myself and now I want to get two barometers and try for myself ;). What ventilation system do you have? Passive ventilation is quite common & up to code until recent legislation where I live. Wind blowing over a chimney would cause a draft. If I’m not mistaken that draft can only be supported by having a lower pressure inside the house. I’m not sure if mechanical ventilation would put the house at over- or underpressure.

Does your house have walls, and do your walls not stand in the way of any outside airflow?

is there by any chance a tornado outside? (haha)

As has been pointed out in some other answers, it is not possible to maintain a pressure difference of 1000 Pa between the inside and outside of a house: small as the difference may seem, it would add up to 2000 N on a 2-square-meter front door, so you'd need to pull on an inward-opening door with something near 500 lb to open it. Very clearly, the instruments are in error (unless, perhaps, you have put your outdoor sensor on a tall pole--the pressure decreases as you go up, and near sea level, you could explain the observed difference with an 80-meter-tall pole).
The question is what is the source of the error? I understand you have swapped sensors (a clever suggestion) and obtained a (more or less) consistent result.  This means that there is likely a temperature-dependent bias in your sensors: when you cool them, they read low.

Open your front door and hold up a piece of paper. Does it get pushed outward? If so there is a net outflow of air from your home.
It does not surprise me too much that there would be this small pressure difference.  You mentioned the outdoor temperature is 30 F, meaning you have the heat on.  That means there is a net influx of energy into your home, and the air is constantly heating up and expanding, trying to flow outward.  This would be consistent with a small $\Delta P$.
Might I suggest shutting the heat off for a short time and seeing if there is a difference.
As a footnote, I applaud you for doing real experiments, taking data, and trying to see physical principles in action.  Physics is fundamentally experimental, and too often these days students and practitioners do nothing but read books about it and write out equations, without ever getting a real world physical experience.

Doing such data collection also gives you an appreciation and understanding of how hard it is to maintain a faithful data series.

I totally agree with you, there is a net influx of energy into my home. So why is the pressure lower inside? My instinct is the same that it should be higher inside.

Did you try the paper test? Which way is the airflow, if any?

10hPa is a huge pressure difference, there should be over 400 pounds of force on the door.   This would blast the door in your face when opening it,  if it were real.

@jtolds: Stab in the dark: hotter air is escaping your house through leaks in the upper part of the house?

If it was due to the heat, then there would only be a pressure difference while the room is heating up. Once the room has reached a stable temperature, the pressures would equal out.
As others have already said, they should definitely not have 10hPa pressure difference, which would imply you'll need a 1500N force (equivalent to 150kg) to open the front door.

Yes, it seems that this 13 hPa difference must be an error due to the need for temperature compensation.  Especially if the barometers are mechanical in nature (mercury, metal strip) rather than digital.  The thermal expansion of the mercury or the metal due to the rather large temp difference would cause an artificial pressure offset.  I would look up the manual of the barometer unit and see if they give a method of temperature compensation

If your internal pressure is 10 hPa (or 1000 N/m2) higher than outside then your outside door (area about 1.5 m2) will need a force of 1500 N to prevent it being blown out which is about 150 kg or 350 pounds. Similarly your windows and walls have even larger areas and couldn't possible withstand the pressure.
So I have to question your calibration and is it valid for different temperatures? It may be easiest to put your internal unit inside your refrigerator (or outside your house) for a while then, inside, quickly check its reading.
I expect you barometer is electronic and consumer grade. Electronic pressure sensors measure a tiny capacitance change as a minute silicon diaphragm deflects. It's so small that it's a miracle that it is actually possible. Many electronic properties change with temperature including reference voltages, oscillator frequencies, material properties, resistance, capacitance - the list goes on. While pressure sensors all have some form of temperature compensation I expect in a consumer grade device it is insufficient for the accuracy you are expecting.
As a comment on some of the other answers if a closed space is being heated the air inside will expand and leave via any openings but there won't be any movement if the inside temperature is stable.
Also I've obviously made approximations and ignored the effect of wind as the [stagnation pressure][1] is small at low velocities (because it has a v2 term)

+1 for noting that temperature affecting the barometers is more likely than an actual 15 mbar pressure difference. I suggest placing the inside unit next to an ice bar (ideally in a non hermetic isothermic bag) and the outside unit next to a hot water bag (ideally inside an isothermic bag, too) and see if pressure measure changes.

Assuming wind speed is >0 there will be a pressure differential between the windward side of a brick wall and the leeward side. I'm not saying it to harp on a technicality, it's a reminder that equilibrium is a construct of science. "Assuming all other things equal" is like "once upon a time, in a land far far away".

Assuming ideal gas law, the ~7% increase in temperature (in Kelvin) inside the house relative to outside, if perfectly isolated, would have lead to a change in pressure of ~+75hPa, a pressure difference equivalent to a ~600m change in elevation. Since the actual difference you see is a lot smaller (~1%) than this, the pressures difference inside and outside the house have indeed equalized, implying the presence of processes/passages that allow this. The small difference (in the "wrong" direction) could be due to local factors inside the house like humidity, environment around the thermometer, air currents etc. or more likely wind or a cold draft at the outside thermometer.
